# I am using aLogCat to view the Log on my Android Phone

Tags: android, logging

I need to send this log to my friend. How do I share the log with my friend? If I use the option of saving periodically, in what format it will be stored?

Comment: also please tell me that where is the log saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a menu option called "Share".  You can share it by email there, or several other ways, depending on whats installed on your phone.

Comment: thanks a lot! can you please tell me where will the log be saved peeiodically? and can i run aLogCat in background? I actually want to start it at the startup and then save log perodically into a file

Comment: The log is saved and managed by the OS I believe.  The app is just a viewer for it.  You can see this when you open the app for the first time after a reboot, it will have entries from before the app was started.  Its a rolling log file, which is why there is an option in the preferences for periodic save.  The files will then be saved at a certain interval to the sd card in the alogcat folder.  And yes, it will run in the background.

Comment: i started aLogCat and then pressed the Home button and then viewed the TaskManager and it did not show aLogCat as a runnig process. Do i need to do somehing to make it run in background?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it doesn't need to run in the background.  Android is maintaining the log file, alogcat just lets you view it.  The periodic save is probably based on the AlarmManager api which doesn't need the app to stay running.

Comment: well it doesnt seem like that because, once the applicaion was closed, no more files were saved in the alogcat directory

Comment: There should be a notification bar icon up while the periodic save is active.  If its not there, it wont be saving anything.

Comment: ok..it is saving. so aLogCat does not need to be running to save the Log. By enabling the periodic saving, it only tells the OS to periodically save the log and the OS remembers this until it is told not to do so. Am i right?

Comment: Sort of.  I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  It sounds like you just need to do something in an app, then send your friend the log of whatever you did.  Just do the thing, open alogcat, and share it.  It will have the entries in it.  The periodic save feature is just for if you need to capture so much data that the log file will roll over before you're done.

Comment: actually i need to monitor the activity for some 3-4 hours. That is why I want to save the log. thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

The application aLogcat is mainly for viewing the actual contents of the log files that the Android OS generates for itself. The sizes of these log files are limited around 50Kb, this means that at most a few minutes of logs can be accessed at most at any given time.

If you would like to record the logs generated during a longer time interval, you should use a dedicated log recorder application. One of these is aLogrec, from the creator of aLogcat.

You can find it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogrec